# How do I document vals in pattern definitions

Tags: scala, scaladoc

I would like to create ScalaDoc entries to every val and def of my class.  The problem is that the vals lie inside a pattern definition, and don't know how to use the `/** */` syntax.

Example:

```
class C(id: String) {
   val (part1, part2) = {
         .....
         (expr1, expr2)
   }
}
```

How do I document *part1* and *part2*?

I've read before asking [this documentation](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tags+and+Annotations) about ScalaDoc.

Comment: You can do `private val parts = { ... }; /** ... */ val part1 = parts._1; /** ... */ val part2 = parts._2;`.

Comment: Good one, I was going to say: "You can document the function that produces the tuple (extract that code into a function if needed)" but this works only for internal developer documentation where vals are private. I prefer @rightfold solution unless there is some special scaladoc thing for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
  val (
    /** Part one. */
    x,
    /** Part two. */
    y
  ) = (1, 2)
```

but for a flawed heuristic

```
/** To prevent doc comments attached to expressions from leaking out of scope
 *  onto the next documentable entity, they are discarded upon passing a right
 *  brace, bracket, or parenthesis.
 */
def discardDocBuffer(): Unit = ()
```

Under `-Xlint` you will see

```
[warn] /home/apm/goofy/src/main/scala/docked.scala:10: discarding unmoored doc comment
[warn]     /** Part two. */
[warn]     ^
```

Maybe the heuristic could be improved to discard only if no doc is discovered on the enclosing entity.

Comment: It would be nice if this could be improved as proposed.

Comment: Created a new issue for the Scala team, based on your answer: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-8751

Comment: "unmoored" doc comments weren't signed off on by Adriaan.